# Can I catch Ubuntu desktop notification?

Tags: notification

For example: when I get some notification with specific text, can I perform some action after that? (f.e. launch bash script)

Simply to say, is there way to implement notification watcher?

Why I need this. I want to perform some actions on protocols which I cannot hook in (for example, when I get Skype message with some text).

Comment: Check https://askubuntu.com/a/451402/621365