# View Recent GNOME Notifications

Tags: command-line, gnome-shell, notification

Is there an app/command that allows me to view recent notifications?

Preferably text-based.

I would also like to view the notification timeout for each notification. ;)

Answer (score 6):

There isn't any command for retrieving previously send messages in [Desktop Notifications Specification](http://www.galago-project.org/specs/notification/0.9/) so my guess is that they are discarded after retrieving.

You can however observe these using `dbus-monitor` command, like this:

```
$ dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'"
```

Sending simple notification:

```
$ notify-send "Hello there"
```

results with following information:

```
method call time=1555095758.597788 sender=:1.385 -> destination=:1.386 serial=6 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=GetServerInformation
method call time=1555095758.601101 sender=:1.385 -> destination=:1.386 serial=7 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
   string "notify-send"
   uint32 0
   string ""
   string "Hello there"
   string ""
   array [
   ]
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "urgency"
         variant             byte 1
      )
   ]
   int32 -1
signal time=1555095765.734845 sender=:1.386 -> destination=:1.385 serial=15 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=NotificationClosed
   uint32 1
   uint32 1
```

Time field is an UNIX timestamp, can be translated like this:

```
$ date -d @1555095765
Fri Apr 12 21:02:45 CEST 2019
```

Comment: This is so annoying... I get notifications from things like the power/battery on my lock screen but it doesn't tell me what they are, and they disappear before I can log in to see what they are!

Comment: Is this tied to a specific version of Gnome? I've just tried this on `3.32.2` and while the `notify-send` notification appears in the `dbus-monitor` output, other notifications don't.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this for over a year
on UbuntuMate 16/18

https://launchpad.net/~jconti/+archive/ubuntu/recent-notifications

http://ppa.launchpad.net/jconti/recent-notifications/ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something with that data you may want some coding and not just a command line stdout, so I am using python here what you can modify to your needs. There is already a similar topic here: [Listening to incoming libnotify notifications using DBus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89279/listening-to-incoming-libnotify-notifications-using-dbus)

I am copying some **python** code from there with some (python3) update:

```
import dbus
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

def notifications(bus, message):
    print(message.get_args_list())
    
DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)

bus = dbus.SessionBus()
bus.add_match_string_non_blocking("eavesdrop=true, interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications', member='Notify'")
bus.add_message_filter(notifications)

mainloop = glib.MainLoop()
mainloop.run()
```